# How to add method return value to list in python?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a pdf report using reportlab and django.
I have a simple table data that is defined like this:

```
table = Table([[x.date, x.person, x.person.company, x.total, ]
                for x in page])
```

My problem is, x.total is a method that returns a float.
This leaves me with a nasty "bound method Trip.total of Trip: 201..." in the pdf.

How can I force the evaluation of the expression inside the list? I'm sure this is quite dumb, but I don't seem to find any useful link

Comment: What if you just call it? `x.total()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call the function in place:

```
table = Table([[x.date, x.person, x.person.company, x.total(), ]
                for x in page])
```

Comment: I feel dumb!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this wasn't working because I missed the @property decorator. This is also why this has worked for me before